# Selenium blank Browser when using FirefoxDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a project that launch test with Selenium Browser, when I tried with Firefox, I get the error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]: Factory method 'getWebDriver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class fr.company.gui.test.webdrivers.FirefoxWebDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class fr.company.gui.test.webdrivers.FirefoxWebDriver
    at fr.company.gui.test.contexts.CucumberContext.getWebDriver(CucumberContext.java:96)
    at fr.company.gui.test.contexts.CucumberContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3688dac0.CGLIB$getWebDriver$0(<generated>)
    at fr.company.gui.test.contexts.CucumberContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3688dac0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b0388c82.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at fr.company.gui.test.contexts.CucumberContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3688dac0.getWebDriver(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 46 more
```

The class `CucumberContext`, tries to instantiate a `FirefoxWebDriver` object, the line is like below:

> driver = new FirefoxWebDriver();

The class `FirefoxWebDriver` extends `org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver`.

#### The error is caused by:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Socket timeout reading Marionette handshake data: Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu. (os error 10060)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'XXXXX', ip: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxWebDriver
remote stacktrace: 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
    at fr.company.gui.test.webdrivers.FirefoxWebDriver.<clinit>(FirefoxWebDriver.java:38)
    ... 57 more
```

The `FirefoxWebDriver` can't instantiate  `FirefoxDriver`, the code is like below:

```
public class FirefoxWebDriver extends EventFiringWebDriver {
    ...
    static {
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
        FirefoxOptions capabilities = new FirefoxOptions();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        capabilities.addPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 8080);

        System.out.println("############## THIS MESSAGE WILL BE PRINTED ##############");
        webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
        System.out.println("############## NOT THIS ONE ##############");
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The geckodriver is the 28 `geckodriver-v028.exe`, the Firefox I use is `Firefox 85.0.1 (32 bits)`, the Selenium version used in the pom.xml is `<selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>`.

#### What I see:

After launching the project I can see the Firefox browser, but it is a blank page:

[Blank Firefox Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEvaR.png)

#### EDIT

The `CucumberContext` class has a method `WebDriver getWebDriver(XService xservice, String webbrowser)`. In this method you have:

```
    public WebDriver getWebDriver(XService xservice, String webbrowser) {
        ...
        final File driverFile = xservice.getFileDriver(webbrowser);
        switch (webbrowser) {
            case "firefox":
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverFile.getPath());
                driver = new FirefoxWebDriver();
                break;
        ...
    }
```

And the `XService` method `getFileDriver` is the method that return the driver file.

```
return createOrLoadFileDriver("driver_firefox.exe", "/geckodriver-v028.exe");
```

The driver file is correctly found, it's then copied by another method `createOrLoadFileDriver` with the name `driver_firefox.exe`. This method works correctly.

Comment: Where have you set the absolute path of your geckodriver in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing reference variable here  :

```
webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

**code :**

```
 static {
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
        FirefoxOptions capabilities = new FirefoxOptions();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        capabilities.addPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 8080);

        System.out.println("############## THIS MESSAGE WILL BE PRINTED ##############");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
        System.out.println("############## NOT THIS ONE ##############");
       
    }
```

you can declare reference variable like this in the class :

```
protected static WebDriver driver;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already have the variable declaration, If I didn't the error message would be totally different

Answer (score 0):

My senior from the company found a solution, although it's a strange one.
The Selenium project wouldn't work when I was connected to the company network, I had to use a VPN, in our case we used the VPN provided by our company, PulseSecure.
I am still working on the reason. I will edit when and if I find it.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a profile but not used it. Try to add the profile to the FirefoxOptions (before the webdriver instantiation)

```
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
```